# How to retrieve specific data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this saved in the database, but I can't find the correct line to console log it.

This is the last thing I tried and still not working:

```
var linesRef = database.ref("/lines");
console.log(
        linesRef
          .child("L1")
          .val().eventattr
      );
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain precisely what you mean by "not working". What is the desired behavior? What is the behavior that you actually observe?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fetch data from firebase realtime database.

Either you can set a listener, which will automatically sync the data whenever there is a change in the database or you can do one time  fetch

in your particular case (to fetch it one time)
you can do

```
const linesRef = firebase.database().ref("/lines");
linesRef.once("value")
.then(response => console.log(response.val()));
```